# An error while installing MySql on a windows server 2016 VM in AWS

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2016

I am trying to install MySql through mysql-installer-community-8.0.16.0.msi on a windows server 2016 VM in AWS and I am getting an error during installation that says "No compatible servers were found. you'll need to cancel this wizard and install one.", any clue what I am missing and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by installing visual c++ redistributable packages before installing MySql.